# SQL difference between the biggest and second biggest value in group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, datediff

I need to find a difference between 1st and 2nd biggest value in group.

What I have now:

```
select ID, max(activityDate) as lastactivity
from activities
group by ID
```

That displays a user ID and that user's last activity.
What I want to find is a time difference between that last activity and the activity before. I tried:

```
select ID, max(activityDate) as lastactivity, 
DATEDIFF(max(activityDate), (max(activityDate) where activityDate not in lastactivity)) 
from activities 
group by ID
```

But it doesn't work. I'm a complete newbie in SQL - I am sorry for childish errors - I tried looking up some solutions online but couldn't find anything relevant to my problem.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Let's say user with ID 1735 has activityDates: 2017-10-16, 2018-02-10, 2018-05-20. I want to diplay a time difference between two last activity dates (2018-02-10 and 2018-05-20)

Comment: @AnnaS Put the desired output into the original question...this will boost the quality of  the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading through the lines correct, it seems what you actually want to do is use `LAG` to get the prior row, and then you can use `TOP (1) WITH TIES` in the outer `SELECT` to filter the data to the "last" row:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           activityDate AS LastActivity,
           LAG(activityDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY activityDate) AS LastLastActivity
    FROM dbo.activities)
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       ID,
       LastActivity,
       DATEDIFF(DAY,LastLastActivity,LastActivity) AS Days
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LastActivity DESC);
```

Comment: hmm
SQL Error [207] [S0001]: Invalid column name 'LastActivity'.

Comment: Fixed, @AnnaS . This is why sample data is useful; I can't test without it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me make this easy for you   :)

**Code to get newest item by date :**

```
SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Table;
```

**Code to get second newest item by date :**

```
SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM Table
WHERE Date < ( SELECT MAX(Date) 
               FROM Table
             ) 
ORDER BY Date DESC ;
```

**Code to get the difference :**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,(SELECT MAX(Date) 
               FROM Table), (SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM Table
WHERE Date < ( SELECT MAX(Date) 
               FROM Table
             ) 
ORDER BY Date DESC)) AS DIFFDATE;
```

Comment: Your `DATEDIFF` function is not valid. The first parameter, for example, can't be an unenclosed subquery.

Comment: Thanks. I had missed the first parameter. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The second, and third, parameters cannot be unenclosed still mind.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `ROW_NUMBER()`?

```
select ID, max(activityDate) as lastactivity, 
       datediff(day, nullif(min(activityDate), max(activityDate)), max(activityDate))
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by activityDate desc) as seqnum
      from activities a
     ) a
where seqnum <= 2;
group by ID;
```

The `nullif()` is so the value returned is `NULL` when there are not two rows.